# difference between mysql and cassandra

Tags: mysql, cassandra

What is the difference between cassandra and mysql?

I searched using Google. But I am not satisfied, and I could not understand. Please tell me about it clearly.

Comment: well, one is `SQL` other is `no-SQL` paradigm based. :) Read [NoSQL paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why nosql with cassandra instead of mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640899/why-nosql-with-cassandra-instead-of-mysql)

Answer (score 8):

MySQL is a relational database, which supports complex, flexible queries using the SQL query language. Essentially the relational model consists of tables (relations) which can be interlinked by keys common to multiple tables.

Cassandra is a key-value store (like a hashmap) that lets you look up plain or structured values based on a key. It does not support complex/flexible queries, but in return it provides greater scalability and performance. It does not use fixed predefined tables, but uses a "column-based" model, where each row of data can contain data items of various types, which don't have to be predefined.

Cassandra uses the Cassandra Query Language (CQL) which uses a syntax similar to SQL. Cassandra also provides an older binary query interface via the Thrift protocol.

Comment: Everything correct except that data don't have to be predefined. This was true in older Cassandra versions, but now you have to define schema before reading/writing

Comment: That's only partially true; it depends on whether you are using the newer CQL interface or the older Thrift interface (and even then, the dynamic behaviour is supported by CQL)- see http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/does-cql-support-dynamic-columns-wide-rows and http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3 for lots of detail! I'll try to clarify my answer when I have a moment free...